# How do I specify nursery-size for Android in .NET MAUI app?

Tags: maui

I am new to .NET MAUI and Xamarin.

I'm building an Android app using .NET MAUI.
I learned that in Xamarin, I can add `nursery-size` like `MONO_GC_PARAMS=nursery-size=128m` to a file (.conf file?).
Can I do something like it in MAUI app? If it's possible, how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it by adding a file by the name of `env.conf` make sure the build action is set to `Android Environment`

In that file then you can add the config, something like this:

```
MONO_GC_PARAMS=bridge-implementation=tarjan,nursery-size=128m,soft-heap-limit=512m
```

**NOTE: I have added multiple options above; only add the ones you need.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assume that I add `env.conf` to `Platform` - `Android` folder. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct